# Schengen visa requirement

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I'm travelling from Bangalore, India to Timisoara, Romania. However I also intend on visiting Barcelona and Florence. Since I will have a Romania (non-Schengen) visa, in order to enter the other 2 places in the Schengen region, I am planning on applying for a Schengen visa in Bangalore.

My concern is I don't want to book round-trip tickets to both Barcelona and Italy for my visa. Is it sufficient if I book just one round-trip ticket with hotel accommodation (maybe Italy) and later on get the visa, buy tickets from Romania to Barcelona?

Also, there is no specific Italy Schengen visa or Spain Schengen visa, right?

Comment: If you plan to travel from Romania to Spain to Italy to Romania, or the reverse, then you should submit tickets supporting that itinerary with your application.  Do not try to hide the fact that you will be traveling from Romania: there is no requirement that you travel from India.  There is also no requirement that your itinerary be strictly a round trip; you just have to show that you will leave.  If you claim a round trip between India and either Italy or Spain when you don't plan to do that, you will more likely hurt your application than help it.

Answer (score 1):

- There are visa for all Schengen states and specific visa for only one or a few of them, but such restricted visa are unusual.
- Schengen visa may be single or multiple entry. Getting just a single entry would be typical for first-time applications.
- Schengen visa have both a duration (maximum number of days in Schengen) and validity period (earliest and latest date to use the visa). Getting just the number of days you have asked for would be typical for first-time applications.
- Last but not least, you must not misrepresent your travel plans in your application. It sounds as if you plan to do that.